# Usar chave estrangeira como chave primaria - Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Estou implementando o hibernate no meu projeto e cheguei numa etapa em que estou tendo problemas para mapear minhas entidades.

Eu tenho uma entidade chamada Livro e gostaria de criar uma entidade Estoque para armazenar o número de livros que possuo, entretanto, gostaria de utilizar a chave primaria de livro na minha entidade estoque para garantir que cada livro terá apenas um unico registro na tabela de estoque.

Minha classe Livro:

```
@Entity
public class Livro {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) @Column(name="idLivro")
    private int idLivro;

    @Column(length=70)
    private String titulo;
    @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String descricao;
    private int edicao;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dataLancamento;
    private int numeroPaginas;
    private long ISBN;
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Categoria> categorias;
    @ManyToOne
    private Editora editora;

    //getters e setters
```

E minha classe estoque:

```
@Entity
public class Estoque {
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn 
    private Livro livro;
    private int quantidade;

    // Getters e Setters
```

Entretanto recebo a mensagem no console:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: br.com.biblioteca.model.Estoque
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:719)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at br.com.biblioteca.model.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

E se eu adicionar a annotation @Id :

```
@Entity
public class Estoque {
    @Id
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn 
    private Livro livro;
```

Eu recebo a seguinte mensagem no console:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at br.com.biblioteca.model.Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.createPrimaryKey(PersistentClass.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CreateKeySecondPass.doSecondPass(CreateKeySecondPass.java:31)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1585)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente utilizar a anotação [@MapsId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) dessa forma:

```
@Entity
public class Estoque {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @MapsId("id")
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="idLivro")  
    private Livro livro;
}
```

Comment: Mas entao o hibernate cria dois campos de id, isso é normal? Minha intencao era ter apenas 1

Comment: @CleitonRibeiro Então adicione a anotação `@JoinColumn` e delete a tabela `Estoque` para o Hibernate recriá-la, editei minha resposta com a alteração.

Comment: muito grato! me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 1):

Para se usar as anotações do `hibernate` é preciso definir um atributo com a anotação `@Id`. Isso é premissa.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/

Comment: eu ja tentei utilizar o @id e mesmo assim tenho problemas: